# Using Node 'pg' library to connect to Amazon Redshift

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, amazon-redshift, pg

I am trying to connect my API to an instance of Redshift using the 'pg' library but I get the following error:

```
Possibly unhandled error: SET TIME ZONE is not supported
at Connection.parseE (/Users/henrylee/WebstormProjects/project-api/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:534:11)
```

I know Redshift doesn't support the setting of timezone, but I don't really care about that. I can't seem to find any help about how to get past this issue, so any inout would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Sequelize.js?

Comment: Yup, I was trying to use Sequelize.js. It seems like Sequelize.js just doesn't work with Redshift since it treats it as regular Postgres and assumes it has all the functions of regular PG. I was able to get past the SET TIME ZONE error with the help of this issue: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/2428, but then I ran into more issues.

Using [node-orm2](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2) instead of Sequelize got me a lot further, but still did not fully work. In the end, it was decided that we just not use an ORM at all.

Comment: Haha, yup. I followed the same road you did. I was really excited after `keepDefaultTimeZone` and assumed all the other issues could be solved via configuration and in the end, hit the same road blocks you did.

Comment: Also curious if someone managed to get to it work?