# Using Sequelize with Redshift

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sequelize.js, amazon-redshift, bookshelf.js

Is it possible to use [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/) with [Redshift](https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/)? If not, what are the alternatives? I need an ORM for Node.js with built-in support for transactions, hence [Sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/) is not an option. I've also looked at [Bookshelf](http://bookshelfjs.org/), but could not find any support for Redshift either.

Answer (score 8):

I've been able to get Sequelize to at least connect to Redshift (and make a simple SELECT query) with these options:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
Sequelize.HSTORE.types.postgres.oids.push('dummy'); // avoid auto-detection and typarray/pg_type error
module.exports = new Sequelize(process.env.REDSHIFT_DATABASE, process.env.REDSHIFT_USER, process.env.REDSHIFT_PASSWORD, {
  host: process.env.REDSHIFT_HOST,
  port: process.env.REDSHIFT_PORT,
  dialect: 'postgres',
  pool: false,
  keepDefaultTimezone: true, // avoid SET TIMEZONE
  databaseVersion: '8.0.2' // avoid SHOW SERVER_VERSION
});
```

Comment: Support for pool:false was removed in v4.0'.        Removing that line, and it works for versions 4.x

Answer (score 2):

Sequelize is not compatible with Redshift. Though Redshift is written on top of Postgres, it is a columnar DB and major core functions are rewritten.

While trying to connect to it gives an error 'Set Time Zone is not supported'

The following thread shows a few people overriding the time zone error but facing other issues subsequently. '[Using Node 'pg' library to connect to Amazon Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28178923/using-node-pg-library-to-connect-to-amazon-redshift)

if Redshift is the mandatory you may use the node-jdbc package to connect with Redshift
https://github.com/CraZySacX/node-jdbc

of if ORM is mandatory, you should may try moving your data store to pure Postgres

Answer (score 1):

Redshift is based on top of postgres 8.0.2 (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-and-postgres-sql.html), so both postgres and sequelize should be able to connect to it.

I don't have any personal experience with it, but the redshift documentation suggests that you can connect to it using regular JDBC / ODBC drivers, so I would be surprised if the node drivers don't work

Comment: Seems node-pg (which is used by both sequelize and bookshelf) connects to redshift just fine https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/686

Comment: This earlier [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28178923/using-node-pg-library-to-connect-to-amazon-redshift) suggests that there used to be some problems with timezones, but they might have been fixed by now.

Comment: The issue regarding timezone has been fixed yes. I don't know of any issues, none have been reported in the official sequelize bug tracker (full disclosure, I'm a sequelize developer)

Answer (score 0):

At this point in time I dont think `Sequelize` is the best option to connect to Redshift. I recommend that you use [node-postgres](https://node-postgres.com/) module directly.

That being said it might be the case that you might already have a project that uses `Sequelize` and want to reuse it in those cases you can do the following.

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

// sequelize config options documented at
// https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#instance-constructor-constructor
const config = {
  dialect: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5439,
  database: '',
  username: '',
  password: '',
  dialectOptions: {
    // either set to ssl to true or use the config options documented at
    // https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_new_tls_tlssocket_socket_options
    ssl: true
  },
  standardConformingStrings: false,
  clientMinMessages: false
};

const redshift = new Sequelize(config);
const queryOpts = {type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT, raw:true};

redshift.query('SELECT 1', queryOpts)
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.log);
```

This will generate the following deprecation warning as Redshift is based on postgres 8.x so consider using pg module directly.

```
(node:5177) [SEQUELIZE0006] DeprecationWarning: This database engine version is not supported, please update your database server. More information https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/ENGINE.md
```

Comment: did you manage to connect? i'm having the same problem but i get `SequelizeHostNotFoundError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND` i tried using the endpoint and the jdbc and nothing

Comment: I didnt have any problem connecting Redshift, I just dont like deprecation warning in important modules. As for your case the error is very descriptive, so check the host/port is reachable and the connection config params.